# How to filter which column is displayed on a graph on Power BI

Tags: filter, graph, powerbi, display

I want to create a graph that will show me different columns, depending on which I choose to display.

My dataset is like this:

> Date / Machine / Loss Type A % / Loss Type B % / Loss Type C % / ... /

> YYYY/MM/DD / Machine 1 / 3% / 1% / 0% / ... /

I want to be able to select which of the losses is presented on my graph, is this possible with my dataset or do I have to change it?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to write measure using SWITCH. Create new table where you put all label to filter. For example:

```
measure= SWITCH( TRUE(),
Tab[ColumnToTest] = "LossTypeA", [Loss Type A %],
Tab[ColumnToTest] = "LossTypeB", [Loss Type B %],
Tab[ColumnToTest] = "LossTypeC", [Loss Type C %],
"elseHere"
)
```